# powershell script install function is not executing correctly

Tags: powershell, automation, remote-access

I'm new to Powershell but am editing a script to remote into multiple workstations using my administrative credentials and perform installs. I am using an Excel sheet to store the workstation and software data. When I run the script, I choose option 6 for the batch install and enter the path to my excel file.The script successfully remotes into a workstation, cycles through all the software to be installed (on a remote server), and then moves to the next workstation. My issue is that when it cycles through the software, it does not seem to be executing the install-file function. So, nothing is actually installed. Any help is appreciated, I feel like there is something small I'm missing.

Comment: I'm willing to bet this is some sort of double hop issue (running PowerShell on ServerA, remoting to ServerB, and then trying to access resources on ServerC). See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/remoting/ps-remoting-second-hop?view=powershell-7.1) for more details. Can you copy the software outside of the session, and then execute the the installation from within the remote session?